# Perl command line RegEx not matching

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, perl

So I have a file with contents in the following format,

```
randomString abc\/def/ghi/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi/mno\/pq/r
```

My intention is to replace all occurrences of `/` with `\/` between two alpha-numeric strings if the ending word does not have a `\` or `/`, so ideally, it should be

```
randomString abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r
```

I was able to nearly achieve the result using this `regEx`

```
perl -pe 's/(\/\w+)\/(\w+\/|\w+\\)/$1\\\/$2/g' file
```

which is returning me

```
randomString abc\/def\/ghi/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r
```

for some reason am not able to figure out why `ghi/mno` part of the string is not getting modified.

Am looking for a way to do this in `perl` command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use lookarounds to replace only those forward slashes that are:

- `(?<!\\)` not preceded by a backslash
- `(?!\w+\s)` not followed by word characters terminating in whitespace

e.g.

```
echo 'randomString abc\/def/ghi/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi/mno\/pq/r' |
  perl -pe 's;(?<!\\)/(?!\w+\s);\\/;g'
randomString abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r
```

Comment: Really appreciate this style, but really want to fix what was wrong with my regEx, am really trying to improve on that way! Thanks!